# Compiled directive with isolate scope variable coming up undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I need to compile a directive because it needs an ID that comes back from the DB, but can't seem to get that to persist through to the directive.

```
$scope.orderInfo = {
  orderId: 'lkdfj232jh'
};
$scope.compile = function() {
   var html = $compile('<apps orderId="orderInfo.orderId"></apps>')($scope);
   $('#apps').append(html);
};

return {
  templateUrl: 'apps.html',
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    orderId: '='
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.orderId);
  }
}
```

orderId is always undefined inside directive.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nRZ3SQaFBojVjRbnppSt?p=preview)

Comment: attribute name should be `order-id` not `orderId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute name should be `order-id`(hyphenated) not `orderId`

```
$scope.compile = function() {
   var html = $compile('<apps order-id="orderInfo.orderId"></apps>')($scope);
   $('#apps').append(html);
};
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Cuxv0xzWUuvQTKPL7HR?p=preview)